# How can I detect salt-and-pepper point in the image?

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, object-detection

I have worked on a project to detect bad points generated by machine for several week and can not find any good solution. I wonder if you guys can give me some clues on it.

The corrupted image is shown as follows. Bad points are very bright or dark points. These points has the following characteristics:

1. relatively bigger or smaller intensity.
2. they are mostly one or two pixels together.

[image]

What I have tried:

1. I regard them as harris conner and detect them using bigger gradients. However, some point in the edge have big gradients also. In addition, threshold for gradient is not easy to fixed. Smaller threshold introduces false positive and bigger threshold introduces false negative.
2. Since bad points has bigger or smaller intensity compared to its local region, I calculate the average intensity except the center point and compared it with the center point. However, some normal points which have bigger or smaller intensity may be misclassified by this method. Also threshold for the difference between average and center point is also hard to fixed.
3. I also tried to extract some features for points and classify them as bad or good points. Although my classifier achieve 96% accuracy, this can misclassify many points because points are numerous in image.(6000,000)
4. I wonder if there is some deep learning point detection modes? I would like to try them to see if they can achieve 99.99...% accuracy.

   Moreover, below examples are corrupted image and normal image. Though they are very obvious for human eyes, I can not think of a perfect method to distinguish them by computer.

   Normal image with some bright pixels:

[image]

corrupted image with two bad points:

[image]

I will appreciate if you can give me some clues on this issue. Thank you so much!

Comment: Inaccessible images, don't use a remote server.

Comment: The `bad points` seem to be [salt-and-pepper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt-and-pepper_noise) noise. Meantime, how did you calculate the accuracy of the classifier?

Comment: @Masoud Thank you for your reply! Yes, I also think so. I labeled about several thousand points and I split them as training set and validation set. I calculate they on validation set based on the labels. Of course, I balanced the negative and positive samples while testing.

Comment: How about estimating a pixel intensity difference of neighbouring pixels and setting a threshold for it and classifying the pixel as noise or normal ? you can check either 4 neighbours or 8 neighbours based on the complexity u need. I recommend this because, there is a clear difference in the pixel intensities. And this isn't computationally heavier, compared to deep learning models( if you are planning to try one)

Comment: You should be able to upload images, they will just be linked instead of displayed inline. Still, they will be on SO’s image server and other users will be able to inline them for you.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a try with a median filter with a small radius (3x3 or 5x5). Then detect the salt-and-noise pepper when the difference with the original image is large.

Comment: @李悦城: did you try it ? No, you didn't.

Comment: Actually, I did. I used this as a feature in my classifier. Although it is useful, it is not enough

Comment: @李悦城: do you mean that you input the noise to your classifier ?

Comment: @李悦城: are you really training on that difference ?

Comment: Yes. I also used other features like pixel value.

Answer (score 0):

Leveraging Numpy to detect pixel intensity in the range `[0,255]` with minimum/maximum thresholds could work. The idea is to create a mask of all pixels greater than some threshold for bright points and lower than another threshold for dark points. The detected points are colored in green

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('1.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
mask = ((gray >= 200) | (gray <= 100))
image[mask] = [36,255,12]

cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: This is good for salt-and-papper noise, whose pixel values are globally big or small. However, my problem is relative to impulsive noise, whose pixel values are locally big or small.